# Flutter ios app with OneSignal failing to build/archive with error 'OneSignal/OneSignal.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I've repeatedly got the

> OneSignal.h not found

error when trying to archive my iOS flutter application.  I've successfully built the app in flutter on my IntelliJ environment using the emulator but can't get it to build in XCode.  I've tried several of the older solutions and was wondering if this is a new issue with new versions of the

> onesignal_flutter

package.  It's failing on the OneSignalNotificationExtention target.  Here is my PodFile....

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

def flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
  raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path

  symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
  system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.

  symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
  system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)

  plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins-dependencies')
  plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
  plugin_pods.each do |plugin_hash|
    plugin_name = plugin_hash['name']
    plugin_path = plugin_hash['path']
    if (plugin_name && plugin_path)
      symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, plugin_name)
      File.symlink(plugin_path, symlink)

      if plugin_name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
          pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/full-lts', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      else
          pod plugin_name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 11.2.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 11.2.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 11.2.0'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.4.3', '< 4.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the dependency error. This happens sometime that your dependency is not loaded completely in your project and something misses out. Try `Flutter clean` and then `Flutter pub get` a few times and this error will be gone. If not so then try flutter clean and then flutter pub get and pod install in ios directory and this will solve the issue. I hope this works for you!

Comment: This worked.   I will also add that I ran pod deintegrate and deleted my Podfile.lock